# Perforce Client permissions

Tags: linux, permissions, perforce

I had downloaded the perforce client in my ubuntu 11 system a while ago. The p4v in my system is found under:

-r-xr-xr-x 1 root root 1578 2011-08-29 12:46 /usr/bin/p4v

After I read the documentation of p4v I realize it should not be owned by root. 
How do I change the ownership of this and also allow my "user" all the access rights without reinstalling the p4v again?

Thanks

Comment: The point is /usr/bin is completely owned by root. I wasn't careful while installing p4v. If nothing works, how do I delete this p4v alone which I installed my "tar"ing a gz file that I had downloaded

Comment: `After I read the documentation of p4v I realize it should not be owned by root.`  Are you sure it says that?  Or that the p4 admin user should not be root?  You don't want Perforce metadata and various server files to be owned by root, but the executables should be okay, as long as other users have executable access.

Answer (score 0):

If you "chown" P4V without changing the permissions, your user will still be able to use it.

For example:

```
chown user:group /usr/bin/p4v
```

The permissions granted to the file allow read and execute to the owner, anyone in the group and everyone else with access to the system. Changing the user and group will not change the permissions, so your user should still be able to execute the binary.

In general, the ownership of a binary that is executable by all shouldn't matter. The danger comes if the owner of the process is root (or any other privileged user). For example, "mount" will be owned by root, and can be run by any user to show the mounted file-systems. Only when it is run by root can it change your file-system structure.

Comment: thanks. Just a little curiosity. What happens when root runs a root owned executable?

Comment: How should a delete an executable and all its dependencies in linux?

Comment: The root user runs executables just like any other user, just with more privileges. Some applications will treat the root user differently because of that (some will refuse to run, others will enable extra features), but that's completely dependent on the application.

Comment: Deleting executables and their dependencies is something you should normally leave to your package manager. That said, I guess you're wanting to delete P4V (or at least reorganise it), so you probably didn't use the package manager to install it. I don't know how you chose to install it, but if you still have the tarball you could look at the contents to work out which files you need to delete.